# Evaluating determinant with entries from ./ output

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations, matrix, syntax

I generate 16 values (this is a differential equation shooting method problem) from this kind of evaluation,

y41 = Evaluate[y4[tf1] /. torsolve4];

When I use them in Det[], it does not work because the input values (in this example y41 above) are bracketed.  Does anyone know the proper Flatten syntax or another workaround? Much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! It is not really clear what your output is, so it is hard to provide help. Perhaps you just need `Det[First[y41]]`? If not, please include how your `y41` looks like.